# common circuit to turn on/off ac motor of 110V AC or 230V AC using MOC3041 and BTA16 Resistor calculation

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, opto-isolator, load, thyristor

I am building a common circuit to turn on/off ac motor of 110V AC or 230V AC using MOC3041 and BTA16.

How do i calculate both resistor value **R** and **Rg** ( With Wattage ). For accurate control of TRIC.

Motor maximum load current is 3A.[image]

Comment: Should I need Rg with power of  1W ( or 2W ) or 0.25W is ok..?

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3004.pdf.pdf

Comment: @Er.Mukesh I choose to avoid triacs, entirely. (I'm a hobbyist, so I don't need to worry about a few nickels' difference in cost.) Because I really hate dealing with triac commutation issues and really appreciate being able to better manage a circuit behavior, I only use inverted parallel SCRs -- as each one is used only 50% of the time. That said, read the application note that G36 provided. It's a good segue.